# Forward slash "/" in REST URL?

Tags: rest, teamcity

I am using REST with Team City:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-build_artifacts

to download artifacts.  I need to download artifacts for the latest successful build for a specific branch.

Currently this works for a specific branch called (that have successful TC builds): **myBranch**

```
http://tchost/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/buildType:MyBuildConfigId,branch:(myBranch)/artifacts/archived
```

But this fails for a specific branch called (that also have successful TC builds): **prefix/myBranch**

```
http://tchost/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/buildType:MyBuildConfigId,branch:(prefix/myBranch)/artifacts/archived
```

I think its because of the forward slash "/" in the latter case. But I need to be able to create branches with forward slashes.

How do I create a valid REST url with "/" in the branch name?

Answer (score 1):

I use base64 workaround described in [comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-19360#comment=27-2070150) from JetBrains' issue tracker:

> .../app/rest/builds/branch:($base64:cmVmcy9oZWFkcy9tYXN0ZXI=)

But there are some alternatives in other comments you may find useful yourself.